# Jenkins Active Choice parameter call function with Groovy script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Trying to call a defined function in active choice parameter 'script' part seems doesn't work:

```
def JustTest() {
  xxx = ['a','b']
  return xxx
}

properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
            ////
            some code omitted
            ////
            script: [
                classpath: [], sandbox: false, 
                script:
                """
                def mymy = JustTest()
                return mymy
                """
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
])

pipeline {
  some code
}
```

when trying to build with parameters an error is received

p.s. 'input' doesn't fit for me, I need to choose parameters before starting

Comment: What error is received? Can you post the information
Choice parameters are a string with newlines, is this what your script returns?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the error, i think its just a matter of ensuring your supplying the correct datatype (string) to the choices param.

For a return type of List, join them together with newlines as show below. If its something else you will need to manipulate it further

```
    List JustTest() {
         List xxx = ['a','b']
         return xxx
    }

    properties([
        parameters([
            choice(name: 'PARAM', choices: JustTest().join('\n'), description: 'Choice'),
        ])
    ])
```

I dont think there is a need for such a verbose choice implementation, but perhaps there are differences in our jenkins plugins. Perhaps give my shorter one a try without all the $class verbosity.

Comment: it not work. I think a reason is 'script' part of ActiveChoice plugin cant access dbCheck() or dbCheck() is "invisible" for it. Here is error:
`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.dbCheck() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

` List dbCheck() {List xxx = ['a','b'] return xxx}

properties([ parameters([ [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
- code omitted 
script: [ $class: 'GroovyScript', 
- code omitted
script: [ script: """ try { def stacks = dbCheck() return stacks;} catch(Exception ex) {return [ex];}
"""
`

Comment: Just to confirm did you try the choice param using just, Name and Choices? i.e. without setting an explicit script?, See my example. We use this quite often to populate dynamic lists.

Comment: The op asked for active choice (https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice). I can confirm that it does indeed *not* work. This is an invalid answer to the question!